# Error:Execution failed for task ':cloudsdk:transformClassesWithRetrolambdaForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, retrolambda

when I'm running the existing project code after updating android studio to 3.0,  I'm getting following error:

> Error: Execution failed for task
>   ':cloudsdk:transformiClassesWithRetrolambdaForDebug'. > Missing
>   javaCompileTask for variant: debug/0 from output dir:

Answer (score 2):

Updating the version of retrolambda to 3.7.0 fixed this issue for me. Replace the line in build.gradle in the dependencies {} with the following:

classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0"